# Java WebService adding CDATA field in response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws, axis

I'm working on a webservice where, i created the wsdl and generated the java classes using apache axis2.

The problem I'm trying to solve is, while creating web service response I have to set text with special characters like *Books & Pens* Or *Value is <10>*  in some of the fields. I am looking for ways to just put these field content in CDATA sections.

Example response my WebService has to send:

```
<BOOKSHOP>
  <ITEM><![CDATA[BOOKS & PENS]]></ITEM>
</BOOKSHOP>
```

I'm not able to find a way to do this. I have googled but found no solution.

Any help would be really appreciated.

I'm aware of converting these special characters explicitly into

```
 & amp ; or & lt;
```

but that does not work for us. 
Also, We want to put just the required fields in CDATA and not entire XML response.
I tried @XmlCDATA but it works only if my text is XML structured.

Comment: The web service stack should handle all the necessary escaping for you automatically - if you provide a value that contains an `&` then it'll be sent in the XML as `&amp;`. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: @IanRoberts, Thanks for your response. The problem i see is when my text is like 'Value is <10>' it ends up like 'Value is &lt;10>'.

I'm using soapui to see the response. Do you think i should leave the values as it is and let webservie handle the escaping Or convert them explicitly.

Comment: Yes, let the XML tools do the work for you. When the receiver of that message parses the XML their parser will turn it back into `Value is <10>`.